# QString find method in Qt?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

Is there any Find method in Qstring in Qt like CString find method ?
My Requirement is i have one Qstring

```
QString strdata = "Sunday,01:30 - 17:30";
```

I want to split them.
Now i want s1  = Sunday
           s2 =  01:30 
           s3 =  17:30

Where s1,s2,s3 are QString

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QString strdata = "Sunday,01:30 - 17:30";

QStringList stringlist_0;
QStringList stringlist_1;

stringlist_0 = strdata.split( "," );
stringlist_1 = stringlist_0[1].split( " - " );

QString day = stringlist_0[0];
QString begin_time = stringlist_1[0];
QString end_time = stringlist_1[1];
```

Comment: +1, but in production code one would want to add error handling.

Comment: Yep, access errors happen too fast. Extracting via QRegExp would be possible too and easier to check for emptiness.

Answer (score 2):

First split it by ',' then split the tail by '-'.

Use split:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split-3

Answer (score 2):

You can also use regular expression to split a string:

```
QStringList list = strdata.split(QRegExp("\\s|-|,"), QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```